# Fetching the List of Keys in Voldemort DB

Tags: voldemort

How to fetch the list of Keys inserted in the Voldemort DB. I am looking for a command line query.

I am connected to  bin/voldemort-shell.sh "storeName" tcp://localhost:6666

Answer (score 0):

From shell, use: fetch 0 tokens 0

or:

```
bin\voldemort-admin-tool.bat --fetch-keys --url tcp://localhost:6666 --node 0
```

// pfredrik